# How to show two fields on a single line with a single label in a form view?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-view

I have two fields `product_qty` and `product_uom`, and I need to show a label for `product_qty` and the two fields on the same line.

I found an answer to the same question on Odoo forum but it did not exactly what I want.

```
<group>
    <label for="product_qty"/>
    <div class="address_format">
        <field name="product_qty"/>
        <field name="product_uom"/>
    </div>
</group>
```

Is it possible to get them inlined on the same line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
<group>
    <label for="product_qty"/>
    <div>
        <field name="product_qty" class="oe_inline"/>
        <field name="product_uom" class="oe_inline"/>
    </div>
</group>
```